# Returning a dict value for a key, or the key if the dict does not contain that key

Tags: python

**Background**: It had been a while since I had read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228181/the-zen-of-python so I went to the interpreter and typed `import this`, then out of curiosity I inspected the contents of the newly imported `this` module and saw that `this` has some interesting attributes, most notably:

```
>>> this.s
"Gur Mra bs Clguba, ol Gvz Crgref\n\nOrnhgvshy vf orggre guna htyl.\nRkcyvpvg vf orggre guna vzcyvpvg.\nFvzcyr vf orggre guna pbzcyrk.\nPbzcyrk vf orggre guna pbzcyvpngrq.\nSyng vf orggre guna arfgrq.\nFcnefr vf orggre guna qrafr.\nErnqnovyvgl pbhagf.\nFcrpvny pnfrf nera'g fcrpvny rabhtu gb oernx gur ehyrf.\nNygubhtu cenpgvpnyvgl orngf chevgl.\nReebef fubhyq arire cnff fvyragyl.\nHayrff rkcyvpvgyl fvyraprq.\nVa gur snpr bs nzovthvgl, ershfr gur grzcgngvba gb thrff.\nGurer fubhyq or bar-- naq cersrenoyl bayl bar --boivbhf jnl gb qb vg.\nNygubhtu gung jnl znl abg or boivbhf ng svefg hayrff lbh'er Qhgpu.\nAbj vf orggre guna arire.\nNygubhtu arire vf bsgra orggre guna *evtug* abj.\nVs gur vzcyrzragngvba vf uneq gb rkcynva, vg'f n onq vqrn.\nVs gur vzcyrzragngvba vf rnfl gb rkcynva, vg znl or n tbbq vqrn.\nAnzrfcnprf ner bar ubaxvat terng vqrn -- yrg'f qb zber bs gubfr!"
>>> this.d
{'A': 'N', 'C': 'P', 'B': 'O', 'E': 'R', 'D': 'Q', 'G': 'T', 'F': 'S', 'I': 'V', 'H': 'U', 'K': 'X', 'J': 'W', 'M': 'Z', 'L': 'Y', 'O': 'B', 'N': 'A', 'Q': 'D', 'P': 'C', 'S': 'F', 'R': 'E', 'U': 'H', 'T': 'G', 'W': 'J', 'V': 'I', 'Y': 'L', 'X': 'K', 'Z': 'M', 'a': 'n', 'c': 'p', 'b': 'o', 'e': 'r', 'd': 'q', 'g': 't', 'f': 's', 'i': 'v', 'h': 'u', 'k': 'x', 'j': 'w', 'm': 'z', 'l': 'y', 'o': 'b', 'n': 'a', 'q': 'd', 'p': 'c', 's': 'f', 'r': 'e', 'u': 'h', 't': 'g', 'w': 'j', 'v': 'i', 'y': 'l', 'x': 'k', 'z': 'm'}
```

I figured the Zen could be obtained from `this.s` by using the character mapping in `this.d`, so I came up with the following line that does in fact print the Zen of Python:

```
"".join(this.d[c] if c in this.d else c for c in this.s)
```

I then went back to Stack Overflow wiki linked above thinking that I would post this interesting information, but of course it was already there, and had been for 2 and a half years.  However, that post uses the following method to obtain the Zen:

```
"".join(c in this.d and this.d[c] or c for c in this.s)
```

This saves a few characters, but it is slightly less obvious what is going on (in my opinion).  So I figured I would check out which method `this.py` uses, of course it is a more elegant solution than either of the above:

```
"".join(this.d.get(c, c) for c in this.s)
```

**Question**: This process got me thinking, are there any performance differences between these three methods that make any of them clearly better?

Obviously the last one is great because it is way more readable, but I have heard there is some overhead associated with Python function calls so it wouldn't surprise me to learn that one of the other methods was faster.

So, if any of these methods are more efficient than the others, which is it and why?

Comment: You could always test with `timeit`...

Comment: In Python 3, there is also `this.s.translate({ord(k): v for k, v in this.d.items()}`.

Comment: I prefer the this.py solution because it adheres more closely to the "The Zen" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only way to know is to try :)

**So here is my setup:**

```
>>> import timeit
>>> cmd1 = """\
... "".join(this.d[c] if c in this.d else c for c in this.s)
... """
>>> cmd2 = """\
... "".join(c in this.d and this.d[c] or c for c in this.s)
... """
>>> cmd3 = """\
... "".join(this.d.get(c, c) for c in this.s)
... """
>>> cmd4 = """\
... _get=this.d.get;"".join(_get(c, c) for c in this.s)
... """
>>> t1 = timeit.Timer(cmd1, "import this")
>>> t2 = timeit.Timer(cmd2, "import this")
>>> t3 = timeit.Timer(cmd3, "import this")
>>> t4 = timeit.Timer(cmd4, "import this")
```

**Results:**

```
print "%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t1.timeit(number=100000)/100000)
362.67 usec/pass

>>> print "%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t2.timeit(number=100000)/100000)
364.25 usec/pass

>>> print "%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t3.timeit(number=100000)/100000)
391.97 usec/pass

>>> print "%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t4.timeit(number=100000)/100000)
246.91 usec/pass
```

Comment: can you share the timing for `_get=this.d.get;"".join(_get(c, c) for c in this.s)` ?

Comment: Thanks for the analysis! I don't write much performance critical code so I completely forgot about `timeit`. Just under 10% difference isn't quite negligible, but it is close enough that in most scenarios I'll be using the last method for the readability.

Comment: Very interesting, do you get a similar performance increase for the other cases if you do something like: `d = this.d;"".join(d[c] if c in d else c for c in this.s)` ?

Answer (score 1):

As I expected (rather *guessed*),

```
_get=this.d.get; "".join(_get(c, c) for c in this.s)
```

proves to be the **fastest**. *See [Mike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505822/returning-a-dict-value-for-a-key-or-the-key-if-the-dict-does-not-contain-that-ke/5505949#5505949) for the timings.*

---

Now, in `this.d.get(c, c)`, `get` **has to be evaluated every time it iterates.**
But if you store the `get` function, it may save you some time.

Comment: Do you get a similar performance increase for the other cases if you do something like: `d = this.d;"".join(d[c] if c in d else c for c in this.s)` ?

Comment: @Andrew There will be performance gain, but a little because there is only one attribute lookup. But, `_get=this.d.get` saves two lookups.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mike and N 1.1 for the answers, I was still curious about the relative performance of storing `this.d` locally before the generator, here is the setup:

```
>>> t1 = timeit.Timer('"".join(this.d[c] if c in this.d else c for c in this.s)', 'import this')
>>> t2 = timeit.Timer('"".join(c in this.d and this.d[c] or c for c in this.s)', 'import this')
>>> t3 = timeit.Timer('"".join(this.d.get(c, c) for c in this.s)', 'import this')
>>> # assigning local names for this.d
>>> t4 = timeit.Timer('d = this.d;"".join(d[c] if c in d else c for c in this.s)', 'import this')
>>> t5 = timeit.Timer('d = thid.d;"".join(c in d and d[c] or c for c in this.s)', 'import this')
>>> t6 = timeit.Timer('_get = this.d.get;"".join(_get(c, c) for c in this.s)', 'import this')
```

Results:

```
>>> print "%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t1.timeit(number=10000)/10000)
404.46 usec/pass

>>> print "%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t2.timeit(number=10000)/10000)
410.73 usec/pass

>>> print "%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t3.timeit(number=10000)/10000)
432.35 usec/pass

>>> print "%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t4.timeit(number=10000)/10000)
244.88 usec/pass

>>> print "%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t5.timeit(number=10000)/10000)
258.15 usec/pass

>>> print "%.2f usec/pass" % (1000000 * t6.timeit(number=10000)/10000)
245.17 usec/pass
```

So it looks like the first and third are almost identical regarding performance once you get rid of the lookup overhead.  These tests were with Python 2.5, not sure if that would make a difference.